# How to change vfat partition UUID?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, uuid

How do I change the UUID of a `vfat` partition?

For `ext2 / ext3 / ext4`, this is done with a simple:

```
tune2fs -U <new-uuid> /dev/<partition>
```

Is there a similar command for `vfat` partitions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It might be helpful to know why you want to do this. I don't know of a tool to do what you want, but there may be other options....

Technically, FAT partitions don't have UUIDs; they have serial numbers, which several Linux tools and files (such as `mount` and `/etc/fstab`) can use in place of UUIDs. On GPT disks, the partitions that hold FAT filesystems have GUIDs, which (on recent enough Linux distributions) can be referred to as PARTUUIDs in `mount` and `/etc/fstab`. Both FAT filesystems and (on GPT disks) the partitions that contain them can also have names, which can also be used by `mount` or in `/etc/fstab`. Any of these features might be usable in place of the FAT serial number.

Although I don't know of a tool to change FAT partitions' serial numbers, they can be set when the filesystem is created via the `-i` option to `mkdosfs`, as in:

```
mkdosfs -i ABCD1234 /dev/sdc1
```

This example sets the serial number of `/dev/sdc1` to ABCD-1234. If the filesystem is small enough, you could back it up, create a fresh filesystem with the desired serial number, and restore it. If you're trying to set the serial number as part of a disk or installation setup script, setting it via `mkdosfs` might be all you need.

You can change the partition's GUID with `gdisk` or `sgdisk`. Using the latter, you'd do the job via the `-u` option, as in:

```
sgdisk -u 1:BC87D91A-02F3-4C52-87CD-536A3DF2A074 /dev/sdc
```

This example sets the GUID of `/dev/sdc1` to BC87D91A-02F3-4C52-87CD-536A3DF2A074. (Note that `-u` takes a colon-delimited set of options, the first of which is the partition number and the second of which is the GUID value. The device filename for the whole-disk device [*not* the partition] is the final option.)

Depending on your needs, one of these approaches may work. Moving broader afield, you can set the filesystem's label with the `dosfslabel` tool; or you can change a GPT partition's name with `sgdisk`'s `-c` option, which works much like `-u`, but takes a name rather than a GUID.

Comment: The servial number of a vfat device can be changed via the mlabel command of the [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/).

Comment: Here's an example with the `mlabel` command : `sudo mlabel -i /dev/mmcblk0p1 -N 12345678`

Comment: For the why, you could argue I'm overthinking this but how about I restored a usb stick from an blank image of another of the same brand/model, now I want to give it unique dos and vfat identifiers (because I probably still have that other usb key around...).

Comment: I think there is a typo in the sgdisk example, it should be `/dev/sdc1` I believe – the `1` is missing.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig, the command as specified is correct. I even address the point you raise in my answer. The `sgdisk` command takes a full-disk device, like `/dev/sdc`, as an option, *not* a partition device. (It can also take a disk device image as an option.) The partition number to be modified is specified in this example as part of the `-u` option -- note that it begins with `1:`, which is the partition number. This is also explicitly noted in my answer.

Answer (score 46):

The volume ID of FAT32 is stored in the first sector at offset 67 (0x43), for FAT16 it's at 39 (0x27). One can use the `dd` command to read it (replace `/dev/sdc1` with your real partition):

```
dd bs=1 skip=67 count=4 if=/dev/sdc1 2>/dev/null \
| xxd -plain -u \
| sed -r 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)/\4\3-\2\1/'
```

And, of course, one can also store a new UUID (replace `1234-ABCD` with your desired value):

```
UUID="1234-ABCD"
printf "\x${UUID:7:2}\x${UUID:5:2}\x${UUID:2:2}\x${UUID:0:2}" \
| dd bs=1 seek=67 count=4 conv=notrunc of=/dev/sdc1
```

Reference:
FAT physical structure (Volume Serial Number offset): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776720(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_fat_how_gkxz

Comment: that's amazing! This is especially handy if you want to exchange a external micro sd-card on an Android device and want the new one match the same path as the old one.

Comment: Note that for FAT12/FAT16 volumes the offset is 39, not 67! This may happen if your partition is really small (mine was a 256M microSD). You can do a sanity check if you compare the readout by `dd` with the output of `blkid` before trying to write to your partition.

Comment: dash(1) (the "/binsh" for ubuntu) cannot interpret `${UUID:7:2}` and the built-in `printf` does not interpolate `\xHH`. So it is better to use `printf "%s" "${UUID}" | sed -r 's/(..)(..)-(..)(..)/\4\3\2\1/' | xxd -r -plain`

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo`, I didn't do it for the reading part and no error was showing.

Comment: @therealmarv Did not work for me for swapping external storage in Android, as my Android 11 says there is a problem and wants to reformat. With MicroSD card reader in Windows and Linux there is no problem

Comment: This answer is old: 2018. Newer Android versions use maybe completely different mechanism to verify old and new sd-card.

Comment: Love it! We fixed a boot error occurring on PXE dual boot machines. Was expecting a different UUID and coundn't find the /boot/efi partition. This fixed it <3 We also had to edit /etc/fstab.

Comment: Tried @Tommy 's approach on a brand-new SD card, which cleanly mounted before. Afterwards, mount fails with `FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0x265f425d (expected 0x26613c5d).` This can be fixed using `sudo fsck -a /dev/sdc1`, but afterwards the old UUID is in place again (verified using gparted).

Answer (score 23):

Often one may want to set a new random UUID for a vfat partition (rather than set a specific one), for example to avoid conflicts after duplicating a partition with `dd`. In this case, a simple solution is to use `gparted`: right click on the partition, then "New UUID".

@tarabyte suggests that most people come to this page looking for a GUI-less (e.g. command line) way to do this on headless server. If that's the case, `gparted` shows that the command it's running under the hood when doing the above is something like:

```
    sudo mlabel -s -n :: -i /dev/nvme0n1p6
```

Comment: I think most of us are interested in a GUI-less (e.g. command line) way to do this on headless servers.

Comment: If you have the ability to use gparted you'll need to install mtools using `sudo apt-get install mtools` or your distro's equivalent command. Otherwise the option to change the UUID will be grayed out.

Comment: I get an error `Hidden (2048) does not match sectors (63)` ... this is from a GPT partition table that was created to accommodate the old MBR partitions. Is this about the space between disk start and first partition start? What's the problem with that?

Comment: Note that gparted's "new uuid" option will generate a new, random UUID.  This lets you avoid conflicts with copied devices, but if you want to set a specific UUID (say you're replacing a device with a corrupted filesystem and want the new one to take the place of the old in all things) then you'll need to do something else.  Interestingly, the man page for mlabel appears to be incorrect about how to do that on my distro, so compare it to what gparted is doing to sort it out. (The man page makes no mention of the -i parameter, but it is strictly necessary.  There may be other caveats.)

Answer (score 5):

Following on [tommy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1294893/1451971) above, the offset for exFAT drives is 100. Other than that, the commands to change the ID for exFAT drives proceed almost verbatim to those for FAT16/32 drives, save a small `fsck` at the end. *Remember, commands must be elevated with `sudo` or run in a root shell, and the `/dev/sdc1` used in the example should be changed to match your device's block id.*

You can check the volume ID with:

```
dd bs=1 skip=100 count=4 if=/dev/sdc1 2>/dev/null \
| xxd -plain -u \
| sed -r 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)/\4\3-\2\1/'
```

And the command to write a new ID becomes:

```
UUID="1234-ABCD"
printf "\x${UUID:7:2}\x${UUID:5:2}\x${UUID:2:2}\x${UUID:0:2}" \
| dd bs=1 seek=100 count=4 conv=notrunc of=/dev/sdc1
```

Finally, I had to recalculate the checksum, which `fsck -a` accomplished for me

```
fsck -a /dev/sdc1
```

I am very much obliged, tommy, thank you.

Comment: To recalculate the checksum, I had to do `exfatfsck -p /dev/sdc1`. Also I had to get exfat-utils_1.3.0 for that, as my OS had only 1.2.8 by default, with which it does not work

Answer (score 3):

I could not change it fat32/16 vfat even from gparted gui. However after installing mtools in arch linux which contains mlabel it allowed me to change it from gui.

```
mlabel -N aaaa1111 -i /dev/sdb1 ::
```

its here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261236/change-fat16-partition-uuid

Comment: :: preceeds the label.  Provide one, or you'll end up with an empty volume label!