# Change volume serial of vfat partition without reformatting on Linux

Tags: linux, vfat

I'm using a vfat formatted USB stick to play mp3 on my car radio. This device seems to create an index of the connected USB storage in it's own memory. And if I copy additional mp3 tracks to the stick, the index sometimes is not updated and the new tracks can not be played.

But when I connect another stick, it will find all tracks on it. Obviously, the index is updated when the media changes.

I would like to always use the same stick (currentls, it's only half full), add new tracks every now and then, and force the car radio to update it's index by pretending it's another stick.

Copying all files to the PC, reformatting the stick, and copying them back is not an option, because it just will take too long on a 64GB USB2 stick. I've also tried a USB3 stick, but the car radio does not work reliably with it.

**So I think the only solution would be to manipulate the volume serial of the stick. Can I do that on Linux ? Preferrably not with low-level tools like dd, hex-editors, ...**

This question is related to [Change UUID of vfat partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1247972/change-uuid-of-vfat-partition/1464789), but when I added an answer just in order to add my use case to the existing question, it was deleted by the admins and they advised me to ask my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that seems very odd.

First, you should not ask a question in a answer to a question. (use a comment for that).

Second, as the answer to your question is within the refereed link, the admins shouldn't have advised you to ask a new question.

Third, this question now technically qualifies as a duplicate of the linked question, and actually should get closed.

As stated in one of the comments in the referred link, the tool you are looking for is called mlabel from the package mtools.

The comment also provides an example:
`sudo mlabel -i /dev/mmcblk0p1 -N 12345678`
whereby the serial number of the vfat partition ( e.g. 1234-5678) is provided as `12345678`to the `mlabel` command.

Comment: oops, somehow I overlooked the mlabel part in the linked question. OK to close.